# Automation of PDF report verification

Tags: pdf, automation

in our team we have a requirement to verify the pdf reports generated from an application. These reports differ from customer to customer.

Are there any automation tools to compare these reports without any manual intervention?

We would like to verify each and every element in the pdf document with respect to the expected output content.

Comment: which programming language are you using? and what have to tried so for? that would be a starting point for helpers to help you in a better way.

Comment: Do you really mean what you say? You want to somehow verify each and every element? I.e. each and every glyph somewhere located on the page, each and every line drawn and image positioned somewhere? Each and every ...? If yes, wouldn't it be easier if you created the PDFs yourself? If no, please clarify.

Comment: @Tahir : I am using Java language and Selenium test automation tool. As of now I am new to this project and have not tried anything. But when I searched on the internet for solutions for pdf verification automation, I did not find anything useful.

Comment: @mkl: Actually 'each and every element' I mean, texts, images and links.

Comment: @user1046367 That is actually quite a task. How much may the reports differ? Do they have to be identically created with only minor differences in certain locations? Do they only have to look identical in a given selection of PDF viewers with minor differences in some locations? Or may they even differ sligthly (e.g. the whole document shifted slightly sidewards, a font only partially embedded, a paragraph reflowed)? The main reason why you did not find anything useful in your search may be that such comparisons really are not trivial and you have to specify your requirements very precisely.

Answer (score 2):

Basically if you are interested in asserting text on pdf files, try searching for some API's or open source libraries for converting PDF to text.

Once you convert them to text, it is very easy to check the contents of it or do file comparison.

The other way of doing this is to compare the actual PDF file with the expected PDF file. Again you can make use of some of the open source libraries to compare two PDF files and say whether the contents matches or not.

Alternate way for comparing pdf file is to compare the checksum of the two PDF files. If it is same, then it means the Actual PDF file matches with the expected PDF file.

Answer (score 1):

try Verifaya Studio, it supports PDF automation, it is free and can be downloaded from http://studio.verifaya.com

Comment: Your answer is pointing to a tool recommendation. Actually this is a billion dollar problem in Test Automation Industry today, especially in Financial Domain. We testers need to convert the data extracted from PDF into record format to compare with DB for criteria the report was generated.

We have plenty of tools to extract the PDF contents like PDFBox which can read the text in unanimous way or the way the PDF was built in. Can we read the report the way how users looks? Like extract tables, headers, footers, images, etc.,?